# How do I extract the thumbnail of a File into an image file in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, thumbnails, windows-shell

I'm trying to create a content catalog program that is used to browse files. I want to show the thumbnail of the files like Explorer does in windows. How can I use C#.Net to extract the thumbnail that windows explorer shows into an instance of System.Drawing.Image?

I'm fairly certain I need to use [this](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Interfaces/IExtractImage.html) or something related to **IExtractImage**. Yet I'm pretty lost when it comes to doing anything with COM, pinvoke, interop etc..

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the accepted answer in this StackOverflow question:
[C# get thumbnail from file via windows api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439719/c-get-thumbnail-from-file-via-windows-api)

The code you linked to at the vbaccelerator site is from 2003 and exhibits several memory management problems.