# Displaying files in a directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

I am developing an ASP.NET 3.5 web application and I have a folder in the project which contains a list of documents which could be pdf or any of the MS office 2003 or 2007 supported file formats. I would like to display these files to my users as thumbnails (just like the way windows displays files). And when the user clicks on a file it has to prompt them to either save the file or open in the browser itself. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't it's reasonable to ask the community to write a solution for you. However, this could easily be achieved with a little C# code.

As a starting point look at `Directory.GetFiles(..)` to get a list of the files and `Image.GetThumbnailImage(..)` to get a thumbnail of the image. 
From there, there are many ways you could display it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the files like this (assuming /Documents)

```
string path = Server.MapPath(@"/Documents");
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path);
```

And nou you only have to write some HTML generating code to display the files the way you want them displayed.

Answer (score 1):

the answer at the following question seems to be RIGHT up your alley (ie the answer)

[C# get thumbnail from file via windows api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439719/c-get-thumbnail-from-file-via-windows-api)