# Is there any way to generate a thumbnail image of a DOCX file?

Tags: .net, preview, docx

I have done this using "pay" tools like ASPOSE, but I was curious if there are any open source tools out there that will do this.

Comment: Great answer with code, samples and links:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439719/c-get-thumbnail-from-file-via-windows-api

Comment: And I think related to John's comment, note that not all Office documents have thumbnails by default: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918586/windows-api-code-pack-thumbnail-gives-preview-thumb-of-pdf-but-not-word-or-excel

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there may be tools out there to do that, but if you can get the file into a format that can then be rasterized easily, it may be worth exploring that. eg converting the work doc to pdf then thumbnailing that.