# Windows API Code Pack Thumbnail gives preview thumb of pdf but not Word or Excel

Tags: asp.net, windows, winapi, thumbnails

I am using the Microsoft API Code Pack and have a handler using the following code

```
    string filename = "C:\\Hello.pdf";

    ShellFile shellFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(filename);
    Bitmap bitmap = shellFile.Thumbnail.ExtraLargeBitmap;

    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    bitmap.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

This works fine to produce a "preview" style thumbnail for pdf documents, but when I try it with Word or Excel I get the generic thumbnail for the filetype instead of a mini image of the document (which is what I'm looking for).

Anyone have ideas on this? Can it be done using this API?

Comment: This link should help you!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439719/c-get-thumbnail-from-file-via-windows-api

Comment: I did see that one. In fact I think I got the link to the Windows API Code Pack from one of the answers, but I can't make it do what I really want it to do. I didn't explore the Sharepoint answer option because I didn't understand it and because we are not using the Sharepoint product in this project so I didn't think it would apply.

Comment: Not all Office documents are saved with thumbnail images.

Comment: Does a preview (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163487.aspx) fit your requirement? Or you want to write a thumbnail provider?

Comment: Thanks, but it needs to be a thumbnail. The client wants these as links to open documents that have been uploaded to our database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David said, not all Office documents are saved with a thumbnail. It's a property on the document itself. In Office 2010 you can see the checkbox on the Save As dialog box. In older versions of Office you can find it in the document properties.

Once the Office document is saved with a thumbnail, the code you have will work.