# How to get a thumbnail of Azure Blob Storage PDF file

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, azure-blob-storage

I am developing a file manager WEB application based on Azure Blob Storage, ASP.NET and C#.

I need to get a thumbnail of a PDF file to display it as an icon of the file.

How to achieve this goal in a proper way? 
Do I need to download PDF file first and than generate a thumbnail on WEB server or there is way to get it done using Azure Blob Storage API or SDK?

Comment: "Do I need to download PDF file first and than generate a thumbnail on WEB server"? Yes.

Comment: What did you use to generate the thumbnail? Can you post an answer?

Comment: I post an answer. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have solved it by using Ghostscript. I have developed my own wrapper for C#. There is example available on net:

[A Simple C# Wrapper for Ghostscript](http://mattephraim.com/blog/2009/01/06/a-simple-c-wrapper-for-ghostscript/)

There are other solutions also available

[Convert PDF to Image(s) using ImageMagick](https://aleksandarjakovljevic.com/convert-pdf-images-using-imagemagick/)

[Windows API Code Pack Thumbnail Preview Thumb of PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918586/windows-api-code-pack-thumbnail-gives-preview-thumb-of-pdf-but-not-word-or-excel)

[Windows API Code Pack 1.1.0 - download link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/winapicp/)

Comment: Don't forget that you need to purchase commercial Ghostscript license according to AGPL. Have you tried other alternatives?..

Answer (score -1):

Of course, you will have to download the PDF and then generate the thumnail. But to optimize performances, you can use an "Azure WebJob" or an "Azure Function" to delegate this job and do not block your web app.