# Thumbnail in C#/ VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, thumbnails

I am looking at the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439719/c-sharp-get-thumbnail-from-file-via-windows-api) question and accepted answer. If you notice there is a line of code like this:

```
ShellFile shellFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(pathToYourFile);
```

This line is giving me an error saying that it is an undefined type, is there a dll I need to include to get this to work? Anyone know which one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934238/use-a-shellfile-object-using-windows-api-code-pack-for-microsof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's part of the Windows API Code Pack, which you'll find on NuGet.