# Visual Basic .net Type 'ShellFile' is not defined

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010, windows-shell, windows-api-code-pack

```
Dim shellFile__1 As ShellFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(pathToYourFile)
Dim shellThumb As Bitmap = shellFile__1.Thumbnail.ExtraLargeBitmap
```

I am a huge noob with programming. I only have a little experience with visual basic. I am trying to use these lines but "ShellFile" is not defined. For some reason there is very little info about this, I must be missing something. I think it may have something to do with the Windows API code pack but I got it downloaded and wasn't sure what to do it with. My google-fu returned nothing on that either. I feel like many of the instructions are implied.

What do I do to get this working? Thanks.

Comment: If you figured this out, you should post an answer and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

For those who are interested in ShellFile to obtain Video and Image Thumbnails, you can use NuGet in Visual Studio to include WindowsAPICodePack (Peter William Wagner - Microsoft).

Answer (score -2):

See the following answers:

[C# get thumbnail from file via windows api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439719/c-sharp-get-thumbnail-from-file-via-windows-api)

The answer has the exact same code. It seems this is a Windows COM library. I don't have the time to look at which one exactly ..

These links may be a good read:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42457/Metadata-from-Managed-Code

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2009/06/12/windows-api-code-pack-for-microsoft-net-framework.aspx

Good luck

lb

Comment: I figured it out, I had to add some files from the API with Project>add reference>browse

Thanks

Comment: For those who are interested in ShellFile to obtain Video and Image Thumbnails, you can use NuGet in Visual Studio to include WindowsAPICodePack (Peter William Wagner - Microsoft).