# How to get thumbnail of selected file and display in PictureBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I am dynamically adding a bunch of files to a bunch of `Panels` in my `Form`.

When I show the `OpenFileDialog`, I allow the user to select a file. When the user selects a file, I would like to:

```
a) If the file is an image, display a thumbnail of that image in the Panel, and
b) If the file is _not_ an image, display its File Icon in the Panel.
```

I am also having trouble understanding how to **differentiate** between an `Image` file and a `normal file` (without doing a massive `IF` statement for all the different image types. Is that how you would do it?)

How can we do this? I have searched but I have not found anything that helped explain how to approach this.

Comment: As to a), sorry but have you at least googled "c# thumbnail"?

Comment: @Alexander, not _exactly_ "c# thumbnail", but about 20 other variations of it.

Answer (score 1):

As to b), I've come to think that you cannot really differentiate what type a file is merely by the extension. That would indeed make too long a list. With image files, I'm allowing myself the performance "luxury" of just feeding the imaging engine (FreeImage in my case) whatever comes, and then catching exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

How to get thumbnails you can read for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439719/c-sharp-get-thumbnail-from-file-via-windows-api)

And for checking file extension yo can just create `List<string>` of image file extentions and write something like this:

```
List<string> extensions  = ....;

if(extensions.Conatins(Path.GetExtension(_yourOpenFileDialog.FileName)))
```

*EDIT*

although to check if your file is valid image you can check it for known[header](http://www.mikekunz.com/image_file_header.html) or just try something like this `Image.FromFile(....).RawFormat` which will throw exception if file is not image,  as Alexander suggested