# Showing a small size sight of documents

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I use a file uploader and a user can upload .pdf, .jpg, .doc etc.

I have a grid like below at the web page:

[image]

At that grid I show the list of documents. And I want to show them like below:

[image]

Any idea? How can I do it? Are there any example?
I want to show a small size sight of documents in order to faciliate understanding at the first look.
If there were only image, I could use thumbnail for it but there are docs and pdf also..

(And the each sights should be an image of each document)

Comment: This would probably be better asked in ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your server on windows you can use the shell's thumbnails. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439719/c-sharp-get-thumbnail-from-file-via-windows-api). That way you will get thumbnails for the images and a different icon dependng on the file type. Maybe you can even get it to work with PDF and DOC files, but that's a matter of fidding with the shell. On my machine (64-bit) I don't get thumbnails but there are [fixes available](http://www.pretentiousname.com/adobe_pdf_x64_fix/index.html).

Update: I followed the instructions at the end of this [article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/pdf-thumbnails-not-showing-up-in-folders/86165edc-9b8c-412a-bc2a-70f8732702ee) and got thumbnails woking on my shell.

In order for this to work you will need to install MS office and adobe reader on the server, or at least create fake file associations.