# How to create thumbnails for all document type in asp.net MVC 4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to generate thumbnail from the excel, pdf, doc, txt, etc. in asp.net mvc 4 application.

Is there any way to do it.

(Any samples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this [SO question answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439719/c-sharp-get-thumbnail-from-file-via-windows-api). might help for your requirement

```
ShellFile shellFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(pathToYourFile);
Bitmap shellThumb = shellFile.Thumbnail.ExtraLargeBitmap;
```

Comment: I saw this post, But i dont know how to proceed.Because that post about the windows-shell.I dont have any knowledge about that. Could you please help further!