# How to get thumbnail of file using the Windows API?

Tags: winapi, thumbnails

I'm trying to get a thumbnail of a file in Windows API. I did find a way, but the code example requires Windows version 8 minimum, I would prefer a way that works in at least 7 or Vista, preferably in XP. If there is a platform independent way of obtaining the thumbnail I would prefer to do that, but I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# get thumbnail from file via windows api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439719/c-sharp-get-thumbnail-from-file-via-windows-api)

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate, I'm asking a question about windows api, not .net api. Or are you telling me that I can use .net api from a normal windows client program, in that case explain how.

Comment: That .Net API is a wrapper around the underlying Windows API.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761848(v=vs.85).aspx http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?527704-2008-Using-Shell-s-IExtractImage-to-extract-file-thumbnail

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to the methods that it exposes?

Comment: If you are not interested in .NET, then please remove the windows-api-code-pack tag, since the Windows API code pack is a .NET library.

Answer (score 22):

There is no single API that works on all Windows versions, because Microsoft keeps changing the thumbnail APIs from one Windows version to another.

On Win2K up to and including Vista (not sure about later versions), you can retrieve an [`IShellFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775075(v=vs.85).aspx) for the file's parent folder using [`SHGetDesktopFolder()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762175(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`IShellFolder::ParseDisplayName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775090(v=vs.85).aspx) (or [`SHParseDisplayName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762236(v=vs.85).aspx) on XP and later), then use [`IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775073(v=vs.85).aspx) to retrieve the desired child file's [`IExtractImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761848(v=vs.85).aspx) interface, and then call its [`GetLocation()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761846(v=vs.85).aspx) method to set the image size and its [`Extract()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761844(v=vs.85).aspx) method to retrieve the actual image.

On Vista and later, you can either:

1) use [`IThumbnailProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774614(v=vs.85).aspx).  Query it for one of its `IInitializeWith...` interfaces ([`IInitializeWithStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761810(v=vs.85).aspx), [`IInitializeWithItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761814(v=vs.85).aspx), or [`IInitializeWithFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761818(v=vs.85).aspx)) to tell it which file you are interested in, and then call its [`GetThumbnail()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774612(v=vs.85).aspx) method to get the actual image.  Alternatively, you can get an [`IShellItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761144(v=vs.85).aspx) for the desired file and then call its [`BindToHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761134(v=vs.85).aspx) method to obtain the file's [`IThumbnailProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774614(v=vs.85).aspx).

2) use [`IThumbnailCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774628(v=vs.85).aspx).  Pass an [`IShellItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761144(v=vs.85).aspx) representing the desired file to its [`GetThumbnail()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774624(v=vs.85).aspx) method to get the image.

3) use [`IShellItemImageFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761084(v=vs.85).aspx).  Use one of the `SHCreateItemFrom...()` functions ([`SHCreateItemFromIDList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762133(v=vs.85).aspx), [`SHCreateItemFromParsingName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762134(v=vs.85).aspx), [`SHCreateItemFromRelativeName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762135(v=vs.85).aspx), [`SHCreateItemInKnownFolder()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762136(v=vs.85).aspx), [`SHCreateItemWithParent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762137(v=vs.85).aspx)) to obtain this interface for a given file, then call its [`GetImage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761082(v=vs.85).aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

Using [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) on a Win 7 system:

```
PS> $myimage = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("c:\image.jpg");
PS> $mythumb = $myimage.GetThumbnailImage(72, 72, $null, [intptr]::Zero);
PS> $mythumb.Save("c:\thumb.jpg")
```

Comment: This won't do since it gets the entire image, the point with a thumbnail cache is mostly performance.

Comment: @DudeDawg According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage.aspx), it will get the thumbnail if it exists:  _"If the Image contains an embedded thumbnail image, this method retrieves the embedded thumbnail and scales it to the requested size. If the Image does not contain an embedded thumbnail image, this method creates a thumbnail image by scaling the main image."_

Comment: @David: That's for thumbnails which are _embedded_ in the `System.Drawing.Image` .Net class. Your random `image.jpg` probably does not contain one, and `FromFile` doesn't try the `IThumbnailCache`.