# Get Thumbnail Images from Pdf, Word, Excel Files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a system that has frontend(ionic) and backend(web form) parts. In the backend, the user can upload files such as pdf, word, and excel. However, I am required to generate thumbnail images from those kind of files. I researched a lot and could not find good resources. How can I generate thumbnail images? It can be an image of the first page of the files.

Comment: Please check this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1751610/795683

Comment: It is generating the icons of the pdf word logo