# C# How do I pull a document file preview from windows explorer and show it on PictureBox?

Tags: c#, thumbnails, picturebox, preview

I’m making a file sorter program and am trying to get all files have a preview in the picture box. Only images are able to be shown in a picture box so I’m wondering if it’s possible to either pull the preview image from windows explorer for if I can add a program in that generates an image preview of any file using the same process as windows explorer. As it’s a file sorter I need it to show actual previews of each file.

Here’s what I’m using:

Visual Studio 2019

C# tools 3.6.0

Microsoft .NET framework 4.8.03752

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# get thumbnail from file via windows api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439719/c-sharp-get-thumbnail-from-file-via-windows-api)